# Getting 0 in return from SqlDataReader while fetching max int value

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am getting "0" in return while fetching the max of values from int column of DB. Each time I try, the reader returns zero.

```
SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection();
conn3.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SHUBHAM-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********";
SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand();

command3.CommandText = "select max(useCountForMonth) as useCounter from tblHRRelax";           
conn3.Open();
command3.Connection = conn3;
command3.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();
while (reader3.Read())
{
    int useCountMonth = Convert.ToInt16(reader3["useCounter"]);                           
    MessageBox.Show("Reader Value " + useCountMonth);
}
conn3.Close();
```

Comment: Why do you have this? `command3.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: where is your GROUP BY in your query?that's your problem

Comment: @Arashjo - not necessarily, you can have a `max` without a `group by`

Comment: Do you actually have data in that table? What does the table definition and data look like? What happens when you run that query directly against the database (rather than from code)?

Comment: aggregates like MAX operate over groups. In the absence of a group by clause, the entire result set is considered to be a single group. Only expressions that are part of a group by clause can be included in a select clause without being enclosed in an aggregate. In the case where there is no group by, then all columns or expressions in the select clause must be contained in an aggregate

Comment: @Arashjo - they are all contained. there is only 1 column returned - the max. What you're saying makes little sense. For example, a table of users with `age` - `select MAX(age) from users` will return the highest age from the table. no agrregation necessary.

Comment: @Arashjo that's wrong. As it is, the statement will return the maximum value in the entire table. `GROUP BY` isn't required

Comment: @Arashjo I don't think you understand your last statement.

Comment: slugster  anything else?!,any more comment?!,if you know the answer post it,don't fight with me if I'm wrong.this is not the question!!.anyway thanks for speech

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be something like that:

```
  //TODO: do not hardcode connection string here (esp. password), but load it
  String connectionString = @"Data Source=SHUBHAM-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********";

  // wrap IDisposable into using
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();

    // wrap IDisposable into using
    using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(conn)) {
      // Make your sql being readable:
      q.CommandText =
        @"select max(useCountForMonth) as useCounter
            from tblHRRelax";

      // wrap IDisposable into using
      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.Read()) // no "while" - just one value to read - "if" 
          MessageBox.Show("Reader Value " + Convert.ToString(reader[0])); // do you want Int32 or String?
      }
    }
  }
```

possible causes of misbehaviour:

1. The *actual* max value is 0 - SQL does its work, check your data
2. There're *no values* in the table (or they are *all nulls*), and you convert null into *integer 0*.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16(DBNull.Value)` throws an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: Sincerly thanks for your reply.. 1. Th table has max value as big figures like 64654, earlier it was having just 0, 1 , 2.. I updated to larger numbers just because I have nothing left to test. I know it was funny.    2. 100% there are values, actually I have tested with some string column in the same table and adjusted the code accordingly for string and it worked. I cant say why there  is problem with int.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `command3.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Comment: This won't fix anything. The OP calls ExecuteReader later. Most likely, the table is empty, MAX returns a NULL and Convert.ToInt16 changes it to 0

Comment: While that line is pointless, would it actually make the `ExecuteReader` return incorrectly?

Comment: I cant remove that line as that executes my command.

100% there are values in table, actually I have tested with some string column in the same table and adjusted the code accordingly for string and it worked. I cant say why there is problem with int.

Answer (score 0):

The table either contains no rows, or all `useCountForMonth` columns are NULL or 0. In this case `MAX(useCountForMonth)` will return NULL which `Convert.ToInt16` will change to 0.

Ensure that there is at least one non-null, greater than zero, value in the `useCountForMonth` column.

There are a few issues with the code in general:

- The call to `ExecuteNonQuery` isn't needed, you are simply executing the same query again and throwing away the results
- Integers are 32-bit. To avoid unnecessary conversions you should use `ToInt32`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16` or `ToInt32` throw an `InvalidCastException` if the value is `DBNull.Value`.